# Ethers How to get token address from uniswap transaction data

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs

I am creating a nodejs script using Ethers that is broadcasting new transactions. I can not find out how to get information about token address. `transaction.data` is encoded. I am enclosing the below example result. I have all information I need, except token address. I have tried some ABI decoding methods for hours without luck. What would be proper way to get token name from the transaction?

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
var url = PROVIDER_URL;

var init = function () {
  var customWsProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);
  
  customWsProvider.on("pending", (tx) => {
    customWsProvider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
        console.log(transaction);
      
    });
  });

  customWsProvider._websocket.on("error", async () => {
    console.log(`Unable to connect to ${ep.subdomain} retrying in 3s...`);
    setTimeout(init, 3000);
  });
  customWsProvider._websocket.on("close", async (code) => {
    console.log(
      `Connection lost with code ${code}! Attempting reconnect in 3s...`
    );
    customWsProvider._websocket.terminate();
    setTimeout(init, 3000);
  });
};

init();
```

Results:

```
{
  hash: '0x2cf879ab1a0419f8f489db54ce383a03509a6eae25e17b049559e030ccb04a71',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0xfB652438ecd86f861084Eacfd851F19b30d8e031',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5968609d', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5968609d', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x02fe32', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x4648a43B2C14Da09FdF82B161150d3F634f40491',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x2386f26fc10000', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 33,
  data: '0x3593564c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063e2e33000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022580dc6705aad00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002bb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d60001f41f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  r: '0x649b6e48f0696d5c4799b20cf08ec28219be079d0c4c8b80322e86b2aa29d332',
  s: '0x26b3859fec9f7c36f71630159f0c154584682a751d7620eecb7d860ae01da292',
  v: 0,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 5,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Comment: please take a look at questions https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144478/uniswap-universal-router-decoding-the-execute-function-parameters and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143239/decode-uniswap-universal-router-transaction-in-ethers-js, decoding the "data" field from the tx one can get info about tokens and everything else

Comment: I actually already came across that post but I didn't find any info about the address of bought token there. Thank you anyway, I will check it tomorrow morning again if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you just looking for info on the chain used then the chain id (5) gives that. In this case this transaction was on Goerli Network and thus used GoerliETH.
you can use chainlist.org to get chainId on different chains.

It seems you have all info:
From, to, value, chain, plus all the gas info